# Add an invited guest as an administrator to an event using Open Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, administrator

I'm trying to add a guest as an administrator using the Open Graph Events API. Don't see this as a feature in the documentation. Has anyone tried this or know if it's is even possible?